# How do you make 2 command blocks go off at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm making a small adventure horror map, and there's suppose to be a death scene where the player steps on a pressure plate and a vine comes and kills them, but I want the command block to not only do /kill @p , but I also want it to say words at the same time the person dies. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: @ardaozkal You don't need to make a comment on the question when you do so. When you write an answer, the asker is automatically alerted.

Comment: I updated it. Does that have alerts? Not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can.

1. First, get a command block:

[image: First, get a command block]

2. Then, dig a 3x2 (with 2 being the amount of command blocks, edit this for yourself) hole

[image: Dig a 3x2 (with 2 being the amount of command blocks) hole]

3. Put command blocks at the bottom (and edit the commands).

[image: Put command blocks at the bottom (and edit the commands).]

4. Put redstones on the Command Blocks by crouching (default: Shift).

[image: Put redstones on the Command Blocks by crouching (default: Shift).]

5. Close the top of it with a block and add a pressure plate.

[image: Close the top of it with a block and add a pressure plate.]

6. Step on it. And you are done

[image: Step on it. And you are done]

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of Minecraft, you can create command chains using command blocks. When the first command block is powered, all subsequent command blocks in that chain will run their commands. The advantage is that the commands will always execute in the same order you want them to, but on the same game tick, which means they will all execute at the same time.

There are two main types of command chains: *impulse* command chains, and *repeating* command chains. Impulse command chains run once when activated, while repeating command chains will keep running over and over again until their input is turned off.

1. Choose which type of command chain you would like. If you would like an *impulse* command chain, type `/give @s command_block` in the chat. If you would like a *repeating* command chain, type `/give @s repeating_command_block` in the chat.

- In Minecraft 1.11 and below, you will need to replace `@s` with your Minecraft username.

3. Make sure you are facing the correct direction. You need to be facing opposite the direction your chain is going in when you place the command blocks in.
4. Place your first command block on the ground. It will face towards you, similar to how pistons face towards you. Enter the first command of your chain into the command block.
5. No matter which command chain you are using, all subsequent commands in your chain use *chain* command blocks. Type `/give @s chain_command_block` in the chat to get one.
6. Place the chain command block adjacent to the first block so that the arrow on the 1st command block points at this new command block. Remember, when placing the command block you must face opposite the direction you want the chain to go **after** that step!

Here are examples of where to place your next command block. Hover your mouse over the image:

[image: Command block with arrow to left]

[image: Command block with diamond on it]

6. Keep placing chain command blocks to extend your chain to as long a length as you wish! Sequencing is important, so enter your commands in the order you would like them to run. (In your case, this probably won't matter.)

**Note:** If you're reading this from one of my other posts, note that I refer to each step being one command block in the chain, and that the impulse/repeat command block at the start counts as the 1st step, with each subsequent chain command block being 2nd step, 3rd step, and so on.

Here is an example of a correctly placed command chain:
[image: A correctly placed chain of command blocks.]

Note that command chains are *not* like observer chains:
[image: A chain of observers with chains of command blocks]