# How do I prevent some items from being removed from a chest? [1.12−]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let's make this clear: I'm on 1.12.

I want to know if it is possible to prevent a player from taking certain items out of a chest. I'm trying to fill an entire chest with say, brown panes, except for the 3x3 grid in the center, and the player cannot remove the panes in any way.

Edit: I'm assuming this is only possible via a custom plugin used by servers.

Comment: did [ExpertCoder14's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/371196/258509) not work for you?

Answer (score 3):

## Main answer for 1.12 players

You need to use `/clear` to remove the items from inventory, and detect whether it succeeds. When in Survival Mode, `/clear` only affects the cursor item of players in Survival Mode, not Creative. This will meant that you will need to switch to Survival whenever you want to test it. A bit annoying, but it's what has to be done!

To be able to replenish the item, you will need to check if the `/clear` command actually did anything. You can accomplish this through the 1.12 version of `/execute store`, which is `/stats`.

### Setup

The first thing you need to do is create a scoreboard objective for the value to be stored in. Here is a sample command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add tamperedChest
```

This command will create a scoreboard objective to hold the values in.

Next: Use a fake player to keep track of the score:

```
/scoreboard players set chest1 tamperedChest 0
```

Next: Give yourself the item and modify it with custom NBT tags or `CustomName` tag to make it identifiable.

Next: Place a 5-block long repeating command chain. (Starting with 1 repeating command block with 4 chain command blocks after. <sup>If you don't know how to create a command chain, see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370298/250180) post.</sup>)
Here are the commands that are supposed to go into each command block:

```
1. /stats entity @a set AffectedItems chest1 tamperedChest
2. /execute @a ~ ~ ~ clear @s stained_glass_pane 12 1 {TAGS}
3. /stats entity @a clear AffectedItems
```

Now, the fake player's score in objective `tamperedChest` is going to be updated with the number of brown panes. We just need to detect for a `1` in the score and we're home free!

In the 4th command block, insert this command:

```
4. /scoreboard players test chest1 tamperedChest 1 1
```

Test for a `1` in `chest1`'s score.

The 5th command block needs to be set to *conditional mode*. The command though, is up to you on how you want to do it. Here you'll insert a command that will activate more commands to replenish the glass panes, or other placeholder items. Here are some ways I think of accomplishing this task:

- Running a function. This is probably the best way, as you'll need a bunch of `/replaceitem` commands to put those glass panes back.
  Functions do require a *little* extra setup, but it's worth it, compared to having 54 command blocks (you need 1 command for each slot of the chest). See how to setup functions using the links below.
  As for running the function, use the `/function` command to run it.
- Placing a redstone block. Using this method is ill-advised, as it will require you to place 54 command blocks in a row, because you need 1 command block for each `/replaceitem` command, and you need 1 `/replaceitem` command for each slot of the chest. But, if you do want to take that road, you most certainly can! Just have it set a redstone block next to a command chain that runs all the `/replaceitem` commands!

Learn more about these mechanics on the Minecraft Wiki:

- [`/clear` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/clear)
- [`/stats` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/stats)
- [Functions in 1.12](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Function_(Java_Edition)&oldid=1162072) (note, you will need to use the page history)