# Display a scoreboard as an actionbar after it has been divided

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/title @a actionbar [{"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"Delay"}}]
```

I want to display a scoreboard delay as an actionbar after it has been divided by 10.

```
/title @a actionbar [{"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"Delay / 10"}}]
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

I'm using version 1.14.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use JSON text to perform math operations with the scoreboard, you need to modify the scoreboard values *before* they're displayed as an actionbar timer.

Because you are using selectors to select players, the best way to do it is to create a new scoreboard objective for the modified values:

```
/scoreboard objectives add modifiedDelay dummy
```

Also, because you can only do multiplication, division, and modulus on existing scoreboard values, and not certain values, you will need to run the following commands one time:

```
/scoreboard objectives add const dummy [{"text":"Constant Values"}]
/scoreboard players set 10 const 10
```

This will set a scoreboard score to a constant value of 10, which is what you need to divide.

Now, you will need to create a command chain to do the following actions. If you are unfamiliar with command chains, please take a look at [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370298/250180) to see how to best place them.
In this command chain, you will need to start it with a **repeating** command block instead of a normal one:

```
/scoreboard players operation * modifiedDelay = * delay
```

Set everybody's `modifiedDelay` score to their `delay` score.

Then to divide you divide the values in `modifiedDelay` by the `10` we set in the `const` scoreboard objective.

```
/scoreboard players operation * modifiedDelay /= 10 const
```

Divide everybody's `modifiedDelay` score by `10`'s `const` score and store it in their `modifiedDelay` score.
Now to display the score, we do the following:

```
/title @a actionbar [{"score":{"name":"*", "objective":"modifiedDelay"}}]
```

Title everybody's actionbar with their `modifiedDelay` score.