# How to execute multiple commands within one command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any way to wear particular armor within one command to be used in the chat (i.e. without command block)?

The several commands look like below -

```
replaceitem entity @s slot.armor.head 0 iron_helmet
replaceitem entity @s slot.armor.chest 0 iron_chestplate
replaceitem entity @s slot.armor.legs 0 iron_leggings
```

I am reading the Wiki about `/execute` and `run` commands - https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute. It sounds like it is possible.  But I don't understand how to apply it. And I am not sure if `run` will work with Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Which edition are you actually playing? You've linked to Java Edition-specific documentation on the Minecraft Wiki, but tagged the question as [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition]

Comment: @pppery, Bedrock Edition. The page I linked is about Java- as well as Bedrock Edition. I see now that `run` command is specific to Java. 

Does it mean there is no way to do what I need with one command?

Answer (score 3):

`/execute` is not what you are looking for. Even in Java Edition, you can only run one command with it.

You can consider creating a command chain. Please consider visiting [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370298/250180) for info on how you can create a command chain. With a command chain, all the commands that are part of it will execute at the same time, but in order. I hope that this will suffice for running multiple commands at once.

If a command chain is not satisfactory, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the command chain is possible only with the command block, but I should execute several commands on console :(

Comment: I know that. I work with Minecraft thru Code Connection (not directly). So I can initiate command only. If I place command block first, then another command would be required to setup it.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, probably, you could look at [/function](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/function)

In common you have to:

- Create simple text file and write your set of commands there.
- Name the file `my_function.mcfunction` Replace *my_function* with desired name you will type in chat
- Create a [data pack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack) ((i.e. `HOME_DIR/.minecraft/saves/MyWorld/datapacks/my_helpers`)
- Place the file in appropriate directory (i.e. DATA_PACK_DIR/functions/my_function.mcfunction)
- Reload the game (you can use `/reload` command for this)

Now you can run your commands in chat like this `/function my_helpers:my_function`.

Note, that this method works for local singleplayer game. It is possible to define functions for server as well (I think, you'll find how if this is your case).

Comment: This looks like a Java Edition answer to a Bedrock Edition question. /function overall is a decent idea, but the details would have to be entirely different.

Comment: I agree. You should probably include both the setup for a datapack (Java) and an add-on (Bedrock) if you want to go that way. The question is for Bedrock, but with the ambiguous title and question description it might as well be found by Java players as well.