# Testforblock on minecraft bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to test for a Redstone block using the `/testforblock 42 6 79 redstone_block`

could someone explain how to use this command correctly?

I am playing on bedrock :)

Comment: That command already looks correct. What is your actual issue with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `/testforblock` command by itself doesn't do anything. You need to create a command chain *with* the `/testforblock` command for it to have a result.

Here is how to create a [command chain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370298/250180).

You need to have 1 chain command block after the 1st command block (the one with the `/testforblock`.) This command block needs to be set to *conditional mode*. This means it will only run if the `/testforblock` succeeds!

Comment: oh also I forgot to make it a repeating command block   XD