# How to target player with the lowest health?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to target the nearest player to me with the lowest health by using command? I believe it is going to do something with health scoreboard.

Comment: my idea is to test exact values of health from 0 to 20 and kill the first player that it finds, it can probably be made more efficiently though

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: oh it is java edition

Answer (score 1):

[Quijibo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/145409/quijibo) has a good idea, and I would like to take this opportunity to expand it into an official answer.

First, you need a free tag name that will be applied to the player to target. I'll be using `lowestHealth` as my tag. The tag will be applied to the player with lowest health, using the nearest player if there's a tie.

Place down an [impulse command chain consisting of 20 command blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370298/250180).

Insert the following commands into each command block.

1. Remove the tag from all players.

   ```
   /tag @a remove lowestHealth
   ```
2. At your position, add the tag to the nearest player with health 0.

   ```
   /execute as YOUR_USERNAME at @s run tag @p[scores={health=0},name=!YOUR_USERNAME] lowestHealth
   ```
3. If the tag has not yet been applied, target the nearest player with health 1.

   ```
   /execute unless entity @a[tag=lowestHealth] as YOUR_USERNAME at @s run tag @p[scores={health=1},name=!YOUR_USERNAME] lowestHealth
   ```
4. If the tag has not yet been applied, target the nearest player with health 2.

   ```
   /execute unless entity @a[tag=lowestHealth] as YOUR_USERNAME at @s run tag @p[scores={health=2},name=!YOUR_USERNAME] lowestHealth
   ```
5. If the tag has not yet been applied, target the nearest player with health 3.

   ```
   /execute unless entity @a[tag=lowestHealth] as YOUR_USERNAME at @s run tag @p[scores={health=3},name=!YOUR_USERNAME] lowestHealth
   ```

Continue with commands up to health 20.

22. Run whatever command you want with the tagged person. For example...

    ```
    /tellraw @p [{"text":"You have the lowest health! Be careful..."}]
    ```

Comment: It's way easier, look at the duplicate parent.

Comment: @FabianRöling Getting to the end goal with a longer path does not mean this answer is incorrect. This answer works, and it did the job. Why should it be downvoted? It is not "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended", and it is not "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect".

Comment: This answer breaks e.g. with golden apples and is extremely verbose and repetitive. If this was done in regular programming, it would be very frowned upon. The downvote indicates that this is not something people should do. Downvotes are not only there to say that something is incorrect.

Comment: @FabianRöling I get the point that it is very verbose and repetitive, but I put a lot of effort into that post. Just because it is a poor practice doesn't constitute a downvote. Just commenting would be enough to get that point across. Why downvote?

Comment: Effort doesn't make it good. Votes in the most basic way mean "good"/"bad" in the voter's opinion. And this is not good coding style.

Comment: @FabianRöling Thanks for your post. It seems like I'll have to study this a little more! You're right, [bad coding practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/805262) is a justifiable downvote reason, but maybe you could have hinted at that a little more? Your second comment here would have done the trick.